# Change TextView to an Integer Value

Tags: android, integer, textview

The value has been inserted from ANOTHER class.  I want edit the TextEdit to be this value.

```
public class Second extends Activity {

    TextView reslt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);
        reslt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult);

    }

    public static void insert(int firstResult) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

Someone help please?

I'm trying to make Integer, "firstResult" the TextView, "reslt".

This is where I inserted the integer from:

```
public class DataHelper extends Activity{

    public static void insert(String firstFB, String firstRL) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Integer a = new Integer(firstFB).intValue();
        Integer b = new Integer(firstRL).intValue();
        int firstResult = a / b;
        Second.insert(firstResult);
```

I have tried using "reslt.editText(firstResult);" under "public static void insert" but it gave me an error saying I cannot make a static reference to a non-static field result.

Any help will be valued.  I am a newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of "static" as defining a single, global reference.  However, you may have multiple instances of your "Second" class, each with multiple TextViews.  As such, the compiler has no way of knowing *which* `reslt` you want to update with the text.

You can probably get this to compile by changing your `TextView reslt;' line to`static TextView reslt;' - but this likely won't be exactly what you want.  Instead, you probably should remove `static` from your insert method, and keep a reference to the instance of your "Second" class that you want to insert to.

Comment: I didn't do the latter.  The first suggestion worked.  Thank you very much!